# Prevent inconsisty in 1:n database relation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, database-normalization

I am having the following mySQL database:

[image]

Each user has a unqiue id *idMember* and can have multiple addresses(1:n relation). Each address has a unique id *idAddress*. The entry *idMember* of **dbAddress** is a foreign-key pointing to *idMember* of **dbUser**.

Furthermore, each pair *idLang* and *idMember* maps to an *idAddress*.

I want to ensure that each pair (*idLang*,*idMember*) maps to an *idAddress* where *idAddress* belongs to the user given by *idMember*. My question is, how can I ensure this?

Here an Example , where [ x ] represents an database entry:

**dbUser**

[ user1 ] [ user2 ]

**dbAddress**

[ 1, user1] [ 2, user1] [3, user1] [4, user2]

In this situation, it should be possible to add the entry
[ 1, user2, 4] to **map**

but is should be denied to add the entry

[1, user2, 3] or [1, user1, 4] to it.

Can I guarantee with foreign-keys or something that this consistency is not violated within mySQL?

Comment: Please describe: What is the table `map` storing and how does it relate to users and addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Is it a requirement to have 3 tables? If so, do not put the idMember in the third table at all. Use its relationship to dbAddress to get the that value.

Are there multiple idLangs per idAddress?  If not I would just combine your dbAddress table and maps table.

As an aside who chose the naming conventions of your tables and columns?  Most times you do not need to put db in front of a table name, usually the id in the table should just be ID and foreign keys are usually the longer something_id.  I have found that this keeps queries much more readable and gives a better clue as to what is going on. I'm sure there are a million and one opinions on that, but if you are just creating this db you might want to think about it.